# Sticky header bar drop shadow not working in IE7 and IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-7

```
#header {     
 background-color:#ecf0f0;
width:100%; margin:0 auto; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;
font-size:12px; font-family:'ApexSans-Book'; text-transform:uppercase;  border-bottom: solid 1px #c1c1c1;
-moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px #000; /* Firefox */
-webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px #000; /* Safari and Chrome */
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px #000; /* Opera 10.5+, future browsers and IE6+ using IE-CSS3 */
behavior: url(ie-css3.htc); /* This lets IE know to call the script on all elements which get the 'box' class */

box-sizing:border-box;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to use the full path to your "ie-css3.htc". See below:

behavior: url("/ie-css3.htc"); /* Paths are relative to the html file (NOT the css file)*/